# A region of attraction analysis using invariant sets

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory

How can I find a region of attraction for given system? $k<0$

$$\begin{align}  
x' =-kx+x^3\\
   \end{align}
    $$

Comment: If $k<0$ then this system doesn't have a stable equilibrium point. So wouldn't the region of attraction be an empty set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k < 0$ and the system is $x' = -kx+x^3$ it can be rewritten to $x'=kx+x^3$ with $k > 0$.

Since the equilibrium is $x = 0$, there are two interesting regions, $x < 0$ and $x > 0$.

Region 1, $x < 0$:
$$x'=\underbrace{kx}_{<0} + \underbrace{x^3}_{<0} < 0.$$
Region 2, $x > 0$:
$$x'=\underbrace{kx}_{>0} + \underbrace{x^3}_{>0} > 0.$$

Summarizing the results in a "phase portrait''

[image: Phase portrait 1]

Here it can be seen that the equilibrium point $x = 0$ is repulsive (unstable), therefore there is no region of attraction (i.e. the region of attraction is an empty set).

However, the question makes more sense for $k > 0$ and $x'=-kx+x^3$.
This system has three equilibria,  $x = \pm \sqrt {k}$ and $x = 0$, therefore there are 4 interesting regions:

1. $x < -\sqrt{k}$
2. $-\sqrt{k} < x < 0$
3. $0 < x < \sqrt{k}$
4. $x > \sqrt{k}$.

Region 1, $ x < -\sqrt{k} $:
$$ x'=-kx+x^3 < 0 $$
Region 2, $ -\sqrt{k} < x < 0 $:
$$ x'=-kx+x^3 > 0 $$
Region 3, $ 0 < x < \sqrt{k} $:
$$ x'=-kx+x^3 < 0 $$
Region 4, $ x > \sqrt{k} $:
$$ x'=-kx+x^3 > 0 $$

Summarizing the results in a "phase portrait''

[image: Phase portrait 2]

Here it can be seen that the equilibrium point $x = 0$ is attractive (stable), while the equilibria $x = \pm \sqrt {k}$ are repulsive (unstable).
Hence the region of attraction is $-\sqrt{k} < x < \sqrt{k}$.